# Android TV TvContract class; launcher-side implementation

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-tv, leanback

There is a [TvContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvContract) class in android which streaming apps can put their contents using a "contentprovider" mechanism in the android home screen. (In android Oreo and later you can see this in the Android TV launcher app). Refer to [this](https://androidtv.news/2017/05/deep-dive-tvprovider-apis/) for more information and example about the topic.

There is an API called [TvProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TvProvider/+/e6f7403/src/com/android/providers/tv/TvProvider.java) which is used to make a communication between apps and launcher. Can we sit another side and receive suggested contents from apps? (For example I want to write my own launcher)

Assuming I have full access to my ROM (and so the root access if I want) and I have all the permissions, can we write such a launcher?

P.S. [TvProvider](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/tvprovider) has no doc yet. But we can see the source as linked above.

Comment: I added some links to explain more. But the question is obvious and if you are an android TV developer you can grasp it easily. @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0